# jQuery function scheduling features

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scheduling, scheduler

I'm trying to achieve this with jQuery + JavaScript:

I have commands/functions that need to be called in a sequence, with a small delay in between them. Examples of those include changing the css property of an element, showing hiding another etc.

JavaScript does not have a sleep function as far as I know. So I'm wondering if jQuery has a plugin or something that supports this feature?

Essentially, a function like `$(window).schedule(function() { /* do something here*/ }, 500);` would be nice. This will push the function into the queue and will be executed as soon as all the previous functions in the queue are executed, if there are no functions in the queue, it will be executed immediately. The integer parameter specifies the delay between this function and the one previous to it.

I think I know how to build this from the ground up, but I'm hoping there is a plugin for this because it will save me from reinventing the wheel.

If there isn't.. I'll build this and release it. :)

Comment: It depends on your functions, synchronous or asynchronous...

Comment: The functions should be executed one after the other (synchronous), however, the "thread" they are executing should be asynchronous. Essentially, this will be simulating a multi-threaded environment, where the page is loaded/used as normal, but there is a "background thread" running the functions one after the other.

Comment: It should be possible to do it with the built-in functions setTimeout and setInterval, or am I missing something? You could use some external state like a queue of sorts, to make sure that the events are completed sequentially (though they will still be asynchronous and not block, as you desire).

Comment: Use jQuery's built in `queue()` and `dequeue()` methods. You specify which queue (default is `fx`) to add functions to, and in each function you call `dequeue()` to trigger the next method in the specific queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of a specific plugin that already exists (although I'd be surprised if there isn't one). But if you just want a general queue that isn't associated with any particular element it is easy enough to do without jQuery, perhaps something like this:

```
function Scheduler() {
    var queue = [],
        timer,
        next = function () {
            var item = queue.shift();
            if (item) {
                timer = setTimeout(function () {
                    item.cb.call(item.thisObj);
                    timer = null;
                    next();
                }, item.delay);
            }
        };
    this.schedule = function (delay, cb, thisObj) {
        queue.push({
            cb: cb,
            delay: delay,
            thisObj: thisObj
        });
        if (!timer) next();
        return this;
    };
}

var scheduler = new Scheduler();
scheduler.schedule(2000, function () {
    $("h1").css("color", "red");
});
scheduler.schedule(500, someFunc)
         .schedule(3000, someOtherFunc)
         .schedule(1500, anotherFunc);
```

The main `.schedule()` method returns the instance of the scheduler, so you can chain repeated calls as shown. And you can (optionally) pass a context for the callback function as shown in the following demo: http://jsfiddle.net/euggc0r2/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's built in [`queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue), [`dequeue()`](http://api.jquery.com/dequeue), and [`delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay) methods, like so:

```
$(function() {
    $('#yourElement')
        .queue('myQueue', function() {
            /* do stuff... */
            // ...then tell jQuery to run the next method
            // in the 'myQueue' queue in 2 seconds.
            $(this).delay(2000, 'myQueue').dequeue('myQueue'); 
        })
        .queue('myQueue', function() {
            /* do different stuff... */
            // ...then tell jQuery to run the next method
            // in the 'myQueue' queue in 2 seconds.
            $(this).delay(2000, 'myQueue').dequeue('myQueue'); 
        })
        ...
        ...
        ...
        .dequeue('myQueue'); // run the first function in the queue.
})();
```

Typically you would queue all your functions, then make the initial `dequeue()` call when they're all complete.